# Gitlab (AWS) authentication using on-premise LDAP (Win 2008 R2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have installed GitLab Omnibus Community Edition 8.0.2 for evaluation purpose. I am trying to connect Gitlab (Linux AMI on AWS) with our on-premise LDAP server running on Win 2008 R2. However, i am unable to do so. I am getting following error (Could not authorize you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials"):

[image]

Here's the config i'm using for LDAP in gitlab.rb

```
 gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS' # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
 main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host: 'XX.YYY.Z.XX'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
     bind_dn: 'CN=git lab,OU=users,OU=Service Accounts,OU=corp,OU=India,OU=Users,OU=UserId&Rooms,DC=india,DC=local'
     password: 'pwd1234'
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: true
     base: 'CN=git lab,OU=users,OU=Service Accounts,OU=corp,OU=India,OU=Users,OU=UserId&Rooms,DC=india,DC=local'
     user_filter: ''
 EOS
```

There are two users: gitlab (newly created AD user) and john.doe (old AD user)

Both users are able to query *all* AD users using *ldapsearch* command but when i use their respective details (one at a time) in gitlab.rb and run `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check` command, it displays info about that particular user only and not *all* users.

Earlier, `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check` was displaying first 100 results from AD when my credential (john.doe) was configured in gitlab.rb file. Since this was my personal credential, i asked my IT team to create a new AD user (gitlab) for GitLab. After i configured new user (gitlab) in gitlab.rb file and ran `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check`, it only displayed that particular user's record. I thought this might be due to some permission issue for the newly-created user so i restored my personal credentials in gitlab.rb. Surprisingly, now when i run `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check`, i get only one record for my user instead of 100 records that i was getting earlier. This is really weird! I think, somehow, GitLab is "forgetting" previous details.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. Seems like it was a bug in the version (8.0.2) i was using. Upgrading it to 8.0.5 fixed my issue.

Also, values of *bind_dn* and *base* that worked for me are:

```
bind_dn: 'CN=git lab,OU=users,OU=Service Accounts,OU=corp,OU=India,OU=Users,OU=UserId&Rooms,DC=india,DC=local'

base: 'OU=users,OU=Service Accounts,OU=corp,OU=India,OU=Users,OU=UserId&Rooms,DC=india,DC=local'
```